# Button is not showing up on mobile

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a button that you can only access if you are logged in. On desktop the button shows up fine, but on mobile (cell hphone) the button does not show up.

I didnt media query it or anything, it just doesn't show up All other buttons are shown though.

```
<nav id="navBar">
        <?php if(!isset($_GET['id'])){
            if(isset($_SESSION['Id'])){
        echo '
            <ul class = "editpage">

                <button id="button" type="button" class= "editpage">Edit Page</button>
            </ul>';}
        }
            else{
                echo '<ul> </ul>';}?>
    </nav>
```

//Css for button

```
.editpage{
            float:right;
            border-radius:25px;
            background-color: #e6fdfe;
        }
```

I expect the button to be shown on mobile, but the actual result is the button not showing up on mobile.

Comment: Can you remove float right and add width 100% on editpage and share a screenshot of the layout please

Comment: although related to PHP - this is more a CSS/HTML question, removing tag :)

Comment: Can you add more of the markup and css?   It could help to see how the parent elements are styled and laid out. Does the element show up in the console? or you just can't see it on the page?

Comment: Since it a part from a list try add li /li before button and comment out the floating .